# Manually instaling apk

Tags: installation, apk

Long story short: I don't have google services, and I accidentally deleted the backup. I can't install any apk no more via package installer. When I click "install" it just says "Application not installed." I tried everything in my settings.

Is there any way to install apk without package installer? Maybe manually extracting apk file and copying it to some folder somewhere and then making shortcut in launcher?

I have android 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you rooted? If you have root, you can use a ROOT browser and put the google services app manually in the /system/app folder then reboot. It SHOULD work.

And when you say google services, do you mean "Google Play Services"?

Comment: Of course I have root, I would not be able to destroy the phone like this otherwise. I think I'm a perfect example of why they don't give root permissions to everyone. :D Do I have to extract it before putting it there? I mean Google Play, and Google settings too.

Comment: So it is "Google play services" right?

Comment: Yes, and I was trying to install it again. You mean to put google Play services apk file in system/app folder? I'm trying it now.

Comment: Yes. AND MAKE SURE it is the LATEST version  of Google Play services. Google is REAL strict about keeping Google Play Services up to date. Let me know if this worked.

Comment: Now I have error "unfortunately google play services has stopped." But you provided me solution for installing so I marked this one as solution, what do you think about installing any other app by moving it to system folder?

Comment: Go to settings and clear the cache and data for Google play services. Then reboot and see what it does.

Comment: @Andrej It is discouraged to place any app into **/system/app/**, and it's advisable to place them in **/system/priv-app/**, instead. Do you have a Terminal emulator?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you reinstall play services and then install the other apps as because manually moving required files to their location would be plain headache. Better you take backup of your data and flash stock ROM again to fix everthing.

Comment: That's the exact thing I'm about to do.